# Using has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a table which has the info for every user. This table is named 'user'. The 'user' table has the column 'clearance', that has the clearance level ID for every user.
Then, I have another table called 'clearances' that holds the description for every clearance level.
I looked around a bit before asking this question and I found out that I can make associations using has_many and belongs_to, but I really couldn't figure out how to use them.
How do I associate my 'clearance' column in my 'users' table with my 'clearances' table and make it show the descriptiong about my clearance level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :clearance, :foreign_key => "clearance"
end

class Clearance < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :foreign_key => "clearance"
end
```

Comment: What's the meaning of :foreign_key and how do I call the clearance description on the view?

Comment: foreign_key is a field in one table that uniquely identifies a row of another table. You don't have to mention it explicitly if it follows the rails naming convention which would be "clearance_id". You can access the description as `user.clearance.description`

Comment: I learned a lot about table relationships with your help. Thanks a lot!